# How to remove Space between row of gridview with images fetched from flickr?

Tags: android, gridview, flickr

I have integrated flickr in my app but the images in gridview shows lot of space in between rows.I am unable to find out why so much space is appearing between rows..

PhotosFragment.java

```
     public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment {
            private FragmentActivity myContext;
            String FlickrPhotoPath, FlickrPhotoPath2;
            Bitmap bmFlickr, bmFlickr2;
            String FlickrQuery_url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search";
            String FlickrQuery_per_page = "&per_page=2";

            String FlickrQuery_nojsoncallback = "&nojsoncallback=1";
            String FlickrQuery_format = "&format=json";
            String FlickrQuer

y_tag = "&tags=";
        String FlickrQuery_key = "&api_key=";
        ArrayList<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

        String FlickrApiKey = "xyz";

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

            if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
                myContext = (FragmentActivity) activity;
            }
            super.onAttach(activity);
        }
        DisplayImageOptions options;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photos, container, false);
            ImageView img2 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            ImageView img3 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            rootView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.icon)
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.icon)
                    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.icon)
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .build();

            String searchResult = QueryFlickr("Java");

            String jsonResult = ParseJSON(searchResult);

            String searchResult2 = QueryFlickr("Android");
            String jsonResult2 = ParseJSON2(searchResult2);
            if (bmFlickr != null) {
                img2.setImageBitmap(bmFlickr);

            }
            if (bmFlickr2 != null) {

                img3.setImageBitmap(bmFlickr2);
            }

            GridView grid = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
            ((GridView) grid).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());

            grid.setFocusable(false);





            GridView grid2 = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
            grid2.setFocusable(false);
            ((GridView) grid2).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());


            return rootView;
        }

        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            private LayoutInflater inflater;

            ImageAdapter() {
                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return imageUrls.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                final ViewHolder holder;
                View view = convertView;
                if (view == null) {
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, parent, false);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    assert view != null;
                    holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
                   // holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
                    view.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                }

                ImageLoader.getInstance()
                        .displayImage(imageUrls.get(position).toString(), holder.imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

                            }
                        }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
                          //      holder.progressBar.setProgress(Math.round(100.0f * current / total));
                            }
                        });

                return view;
            }
        }
        static class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageView;
            ProgressBar progressBar;
        }

        private String QueryFlickr(String q) {

            String qResult = null;

            String qString =
                    FlickrQuery_url
                            + FlickrQuery_per_page
                            + FlickrQuery_nojsoncallback
                            + FlickrQuery_format
                            + FlickrQuery_tag + q
                            + FlickrQuery_key + FlickrApiKey;

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(qString);


            try {
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();

                if (httpEntity != null) {
                    InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
                    Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String stringReadLine = null;

                    while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n");
                    }

                    qResult = stringBuilder.toString();

                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return qResult;
        }

        private String ParseJSON(String json) {

            String jResult = null;
            //  String jResult2 = null;
            bmFlickr = null;

            String flickrId;
            String flickrOwner;
            String flickrSecret;
            String flickrServer;
            String flickrFarm;
            String flickrTitle;

            try {
                JSONObject JsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                JSONObject Json_photos = JsonObject.getJSONObject("photos");
                JSONArray JsonArray_photo = Json_photos.getJSONArray("photo");

                //We have only one photo in this exercise
                JSONObject FlickrPhoto = JsonArray_photo.getJSONObject(0);

                flickrId = FlickrPhoto.getString("id");
                flickrOwner = FlickrPhoto.getString("owner");
                flickrSecret = FlickrPhoto.getString("secret");
                flickrServer = FlickrPhoto.getString("server");
                flickrFarm = FlickrPhoto.getString("farm");
                flickrTitle = FlickrPhoto.getString("title");

                jResult = "\nid: " + flickrId + "\n"
                        + "owner: " + flickrOwner + "\n"
                        + "secret: " + flickrSecret + "\n"
                        + "server: " + flickrServer + "\n"
                        + "farm: " + flickrFarm + "\n"
                        + "title: " + flickrTitle + "\n";
        /*      jResult2 = "\nid: " + flickrId + "\n"
                        + "owner: " + flickrOwner + "\n"
                        + "secret: " + flickrSecret + "\n"
                        + "server: " + flickrServer + "\n"
                        + "farm: " + flickrFarm + "\n"
                        + "title: " + flickrTitle + "\n"; */

                bmFlickr = LoadPhotoFromFlickr(flickrId, flickrOwner, flickrSecret,
                        flickrServer, flickrFarm, flickrTitle);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return jResult;
        }

        private String ParseJSON2(String json) {

            String jResult = null;
            //  String jResult2 = null;
            bmFlickr2 = null;

            String flickrId;
            String flickrOwner;
            String flickrSecret;
            String flickrServer;
            String flickrFarm;
            String flickrTitle;

            try {
                JSONObject JsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                JSONObject Json_photos = JsonObject.getJSONObject("photos");
                JSONArray JsonArray_photo = Json_photos.getJSONArray("photo");

                //We have only one photo in this exercise
                JSONObject FlickrPhoto = JsonArray_photo.getJSONObject(0);

                flickrId = FlickrPhoto.getString("id");
                flickrOwner = FlickrPhoto.getString("owner");
                flickrSecret = FlickrPhoto.getString("secret");
                flickrServer = FlickrPhoto.getString("server");
                flickrFarm = FlickrPhoto.getString("farm");
                flickrTitle = FlickrPhoto.getString("title");

                jResult = "\nid: " + flickrId + "\n"
                        + "owner: " + flickrOwner + "\n"
                        + "secret: " + flickrSecret + "\n"
                        + "server: " + flickrServer + "\n"
                        + "farm: " + flickrFarm + "\n"
                        + "title: " + flickrTitle + "\n";
        /*      jResult2 = "\nid: " + flickrId + "\n"
                        + "owner: " + flickrOwner + "\n"
                        + "secret: " + flickrSecret + "\n"
                        + "server: " + flickrServer + "\n"
                        + "farm: " + flickrFarm + "\n"
                        + "title: " + flickrTitle + "\n"; */

                bmFlickr2 = LoadPhotoFromFlickr2(flickrId, flickrOwner, flickrSecret,
                        flickrServer, flickrFarm, flickrTitle);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return jResult;
        }

        private Bitmap LoadPhotoFromFlickr(
                String id, String owner, String secret,
                String server, String farm, String title) {
            Bitmap bm = null;

            FlickrPhotoPath =
                    "http://farm" + farm + ".static.flickr.com/"
                            + server + "/" + id + "_" + secret + "_m.jpg";
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath);
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath);
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath);
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath);
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath);
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath);
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath);
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath);

            URL FlickrPhotoUrl = null;

            try {
                FlickrPhotoUrl = new URL(FlickrPhotoPath);

                HttpURLConnection httpConnection
                        = (HttpURLConnection) FlickrPhotoUrl.openConnection();
                httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return bm;
        }

        private Bitmap LoadPhotoFromFlickr2(
                String id, String owner, String secret,
                String server, String farm, String title) {
            Bitmap bm = null;

            FlickrPhotoPath2 =
                    "http://farm" + farm + ".static.flickr.com/"
                            + server + "/" + id + "_" + secret + "_m.jpg";
                    imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath2);
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath2);
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath2);
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath2);
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath2);
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath2);
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath2);
            imageUrls.add(FlickrPhotoPath2);



            URL FlickrPhotoUrl2 = null;

            try {
                FlickrPhotoUrl2 = new URL(FlickrPhotoPath2);

                HttpURLConnection httpConnection
                        = (HttpURLConnection) FlickrPhotoUrl2.openConnection();
                httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return bm;
        }

    }
```

photos.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"


                 />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="210dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"


          />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="210dp"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"

                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:numColumns="2"


                android:scaleType="fitXY"

                ></GridView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout2"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <com.pepup.league.ui.fonts.AvenirNextLtRegular
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="JULY-2014"
                android:textColor="#b2b2b2"

                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
                android:background="#b2b2b2" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
                android:background="#b2b2b2" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout3">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"

                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
                android:numColumns="5"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="0dp"></GridView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

grid_single.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"></ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you use `android:padding="5dp"` in grid_single.xm in `LinearLayout`. If you want remove spaces you need use xml like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"></ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i removed android:padding="5dp" but still its showing lot of space between rows..